# Triple booting Windows and 2 installations of Ubuntu 22.04, cloning the ubuntu installs

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, clone

My issue seems to be a bit specific. I have 3 partitions for OS installs. Windows 11 is on one, and Ubuntu 22.04 is on the other. I have a 3rd partition the exact size as the Ubuntu, and would like to clone it. The reason I want to do it this way is to experiment with different settings, extensions, apps, etc. and when I find what I like, install it on my original daily driver, then re-clone the 2nd Ubuntu again, so I keep a fairly clean install. I don't want to use a virtual machine. I want to see how things work in real life on my actual hardware. The 2nd Ubuntu is essentially testing.

How do I handle the grub config with the cloned partition? I'm hoping for an answer before I actually attempt this.

Comment: You cannot clone on same system, and reboot with both clones. You cannot have duplicate UUIDs and if UEFI/gpt duplicate GUIDs. Easy to just do another install & copy hidden files in /home to new install. I use separate data partition so I can have all data in each install. Last install controls grub, unless you change it. I keep main working install as default boot and add other installs into 40_custom. I do not use os-prober, except once at beginning of install to see any changes in standard grub config.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can make it work like that.